# Recording DNS lookup tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, dns

For HTTP I can use a library like [node-replay](https://github.com/assaf/node-replay) or [sepia](https://github.com/linkedin/sepia) to record any responses to fixtures that I can use on new test runs.

I'm building a simple library where I use DNS lookup/resolve, so I want to record this and play back the response so tests won't break in the future (should  a domain I test suddenly be taken for example) and because of speed.

How should I be testing my library if I don't want to do real lookups for each test?

Comment: How many tests are we talking? You could just cache them in an external json file - each time you run a new one, if it doesn't exist in the cache, create it? If you've got a lot (1000s) though, that might not be very performant, and you might need to look into a micro db or something like redis.

Comment: It will _max_ be tens of tests, I doubt it will even be 100. I don't know how you would cache it in an external JSON, can you share a guide or provide an example to show how it could be done?

Comment: Just use `fs` to write to a file - create an array/object in your Javascript and then write it out.

Comment: If the DNS resolve is part of the test, then you would not want to cache the responses. If the resolution isn't part of the test, then why not just use static entries?